# libusb program not compiling

Tags: compiling, c

I am trying to compile a program that uses `libusb` library in Ubuntu 12.04.

I have installed the `libusb-1.0-0-dev`. However, when I try to compile a program as below:

```
#include<usb.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
int main()
{
       libusb_init(NULL);            
       return 0;
}
```

It gives me an error saying

```
/tmp/ccb75YtE.o: In function 'main':
usb.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to 'libusb_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using the  command `cc <file name> -lusb` to compile it.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Nitpicking: Should that be **int** main() ? (And a return 0; at the end). Not that it matters for this error, but doing it right is a good habit.

Comment: Please edit your answer with the command you are using to compile. If you're using a makefile, post its content too.

Comment: @Jesse Command to compile added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the **-lusb** to **-lusb-1.0**, like this:
`$ cc <file name> -lusb-1.0`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `-lusb` command to the linker. You're including the header but you also must link the code to the libusb library (which also must be installed)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say thanks for the comment about changing lusb to lusb 1.0, I didnt change the headers, but did install libusb-1.0(Which is found on antinquated 32 bit machines) ; the app Im using now compiles, more importantly I just wanted to include a bit of context about the issue Im going through and I may help someone else in the same boat.

Basically Ive succeeded in compiling ttwatch (An app for Tomtom spark, and other watches) Ive had tried it every which way I can imagine in a modern PC, but it just wont compile.

The github link is here
https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch

The problem was that the app I think was originally compiled on a 32 bit machine, so what I did in the end was ran a virtualbox session and installed an old ubuntu OS on it (Xenial Xeru if I remember rightly) I found and installed libusb-1.0 (Which cannot be found on modern OS) and Voila! It compiled!

Hope this helps someone in the same boat.

Whether the USB connects to the watch through a virtualbox session remains to be seen.